# How to change the content length in request?

Tags: request, response, content-length

It's regarding content length.

I know its use. It tells the receiver that "this much" data I am sending.

It's available with both request & response. In Java, we have setContentLength() method for response, we can set content length to some value using this method and browser is going to read only up to that point in the body.

In request, we don't have any setContentLength() method - at least not in Java. So I believe browser sets this as per the data request is containing. Now let’s say if I modify this request in between – change a parameter value to some bigger value, how do I change the content length? If I don’t change content length, server doesn’t read the complete body – it only reads up to content length & ignores rest of the body content.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks.

PS: I am changing request in a C filter in web server before request goes to application server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to change content length of request, I don't think you can achieve that simply, the only way i can think of is parse the content of request, the strip unneeded data and the generate the request that simple mimics original request but contains stripped data, it also depends on the whenever you are using POST or GET requests